# Redirecting certain visitors to another domain while retaining entire query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, url-parameters

Can anyone help with the following? We need to send visitors that reach our site with one of four 'campaign' values in the query string to another domain, while retaining the entire query string. For example, a user lands on our site with the follow URL:

```
http://alpha.testing.com/landing412?ecampaign=Z123&campaign=201&trackId=123qwe456rty&media=poi098uyt765
```

If they have one of four 'campaign' variables:

```
campaign=201
campaign=221
campaign=301
campaign=321
```

Since campaign is equal to 201 in the example above, they would need to be redirected here with the following URL:

```
http://beta.testing.com/landing412?ecampaign=Z123&campaign=201&trackId=123qwe456rty&media=poi098uyt765
```

UPDATE:
Here's what I have in place now, which is working.

```
var cmp = (new URL(location)).searchParams.get('campaign')
var uri = 'http://beta.testing.com/landing412';
uri = uri + document.location.search;
if ((cmp == 201) || (cmp == 221) || (cmp == 301) || (cmp == 321)) 
{
window.location = uri;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: 2pha - I modified the original post with what I've already tried and it's now working fine. Thanks.